# iOS App crashes on launch no device while debugging only - not in simulator or during normal device app launch

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to determine what's causing a crash I'm seeing while testing my app. It now throws  EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1) each time I try to run the app from xcode with the iphone connected.

The app crashes but I don't see a new entry in the crash log.I've tried running with Zombies enabled but I get the same crash.

Weird thing is if I debug with the simulator, run the app on the device by tapping its icon, or even in Instruments, I don't get this error. Any suggestion and/or explanation would be very much appreciated.

Here's what I see in Xcode:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x36acb5c0:  teq.w  r0, #0
0x36acb5c4:  beq    0x36acb606                ; objc_msgSend + 70
0x36acb5c6:  push.w {r3, r4}

**0x36acb5ca:  ldr    r4, [r0]**  < ------ This is where the app gets caught up EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

0x36acb5cc:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2
0x36acb5d0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]
0x36acb5d2:  add.w  r3, r3, #8
0x36acb5d6:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8]
0x36acb5da:  and.w  r9, r9, r12
0x36acb5de:  ldr.w  r4, [r3, r9, lsl #2]
0x36acb5e2:  teq.w  r4, #0
0x36acb5e6:  add.w  r9, r9, #1
0x36acb5ea:  beq    0x36acb600                ; objc_msgSend + 64
0x36acb5ec:  ldr.w  r12, [r4]
0x36acb5f0:  teq.w  r1, r12
0x36acb5f4:  bne    0x36acb5d6                ; objc_msgSend + 22
0x36acb5f6:  ldr.w  r12, [r4, #8]
0x36acb5fa:  pop.w  {r3, r4}
0x36acb5fe:  bx     r12
0x36acb600:  pop.w  {r3, r4}
0x36acb604:  b      0x36acb620                ; objc_msgSend_uncached
0x36acb606:  mov.w  r1, #0
0x36acb60a:  bx     lr
0x36acb60c:  nop    
0x36acb60e:  nop    
0x36acb610:  nop    
0x36acb612:  nop    
0x36acb614:  nop    
0x36acb616:  nop    
0x36acb618:  nop    
0x36acb61a:  nop    
0x36acb61c:  nop    
0x36acb61e:  nop
```

Comment: are you using ARC? Did you try debugging with zombies enabled?

Comment: I am using ARC. Sorry forgot to mention I've tried enabling Zombies in Xcode but get the same crash on launch

Comment: In that case, I would try commenting out parts of your code and narrow it down that way... For example, does it still crash if you remove `UIApplicationMain` from your `main`?

Comment: Yes it does. I get the same crash whether its there or not. I commented out this line:

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MYAppDelegate class]));

Comment: Try cleaning your entire build folder/ remove app from your device

Comment: I have tried deleting the app from device with no success. I don't understand what you mean by cleaning the build folder? I've tried running the clean in XCode and that succeeds.

Comment: hold option while choosing Clean from the build menu--it should change to "Clean build folder...".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23005/discussion-between-bluedude-and-nielsbot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, reboot your device. Works fine now. Could not isolate what was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable all memory debugging options in cmd-alt-b menu: zombies, scribble, etc. And set exception breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add to my question. Yes I've tried Zombies but the app still crashes on launch every time